# In NetBeans, where is the codenameone_settings.properties file?

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to delete build hints using the CodenameOne Settings tool, but the hints keep returning. I would like to try deleting the hints directly from the properties file.

Comment: The unwanted build hint, for BrainTree, is preventing my build.

Comment: It is in the project directory and I can edit it from notepad++. I was looking to edit it through the NetBeans interface.

Comment: FYI editing the file directly won't make a difference. The braintree settings are a part of the braintree cn1lib specifically https://github.com/codenameone/BraintreeCodenameOne/blob/master/codenameone_library_appended.properties and https://github.com/codenameone/BraintreeCodenameOne/blob/master/codenameone_library_required.properties

Answer (score 1):

It is directly accessible in the project directory.